# Knex MySQL Migration "Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction query already complete"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, innodb, knex.js

I'm new to pretty much everything.  I tried using a single migration file to create all the tables in a MySQL database (20 tables).

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {

function createTable1() {
    return knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('Table1', (t) => {
      t.increments('id').primary();
      t.string('col_1', 48).unique().notNullable();
      t.timestamps(true, true);
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

function createTable2() {
    return knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('Table2', (t) => {
      t.increments('id').primary();
      t.string('col_1', 48).unique().notNullable();
      t.integer('someId').unsigned().references('Table1.id')
      t.timestamps(true, true);
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

function createTable3() {
    return knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('Table3', (t) => {
      t.increments('id').primary();
      t.string('col_1', 48).unique().notNullable();
      t.integer('someId').unsigned().references('Table1.id')
      t.integer('someOtherId').unsigned().references('Table2.id')
      t.timestamps(true, true);
    }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
... //similar functions for all 20 tables

return Promise.all([
    createTable1()
    .then(createTable2())
    .then(createTable3())
    ...
    .then(createTable20())
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.sql))
  ]);
}

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

  return knex.schema.dropTable('Table1')
  .then(knex.schema.dropTable('Table2'))
  .then(knex.schema.dropTable('Table3'))
  ...
  .then(knex.schema.dropTable('Table20'))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e.sql))
};
```

I expected knex to execute all of the sql queries in one transaction

The migration executes but generates the following error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction query already complete, run
>   with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info

Admittedly I don't have a firm grasp with how to use promises correctly and I understand that the return Promise.all block will not necessarily generate & execute the SQL queries in that same order, but should I even be doing this?  Does it make more sense to create a separate migration file for each table?

Comment: > Does it make more sense to create a separate migration file for each table? 

i think it's more common to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking functions in your promise chain instead of chaining them. The first function should be executed and then chained with other functions in the `.then`. You also seem to be mixing up promise chaining and the usage of `Promise.all`.

If you want each table to be created sequentially drop the `Promise.all` and the function calls:

```
return createTable1()
  .then(createTable2)
  .then(createTable3)
  ...
  .then(createTable20)
  .catch((e) => console.log(e.sql))
```

If you want to create N tables all at the same time use `Promise.all` like this:

```
return Promise.all([createTable1(), createTable2(), ..., createTable20()])
```